# How to add a hyperlink for downloading a dataframe as csv using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, streamlit

I'm working with a `.csv` cars dataset (that I got from [here](https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/data/cars.csv)) and I'm trying to:

1. Convert this `.csv` to a pandas dataframe ***(Done, see df)***
2. Group the dataframe by cars models ***(Done, see grouped_df)***
3. Make a column with a hyperlink to download the `.csv/df` for each car in the `grouped_df` ***(To be finalized)***

#### CODE :

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML

df = pd.read_csv("cars.csv", delimiter=';', skiprows=[1])

display(df.head(5))

grouped_df = df.groupby('Car').agg(NumberOfCars=('Car', 'size'), 
                                   MeanOfWeight=('Weight', 'mean'),
                                   MeanOfAcceleration=('Acceleration', 'mean'))

grouped_df.insert(len(grouped_df.columns), "DownloadCsv", 'Download the details (.csv)')

grouped_df['DownloadCsv'] = grouped_df['DownloadCsv'].apply(lambda x: f'<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/{x}">{x}</a>')

HTML(grouped_df.sample(5).to_html(escape=False))
```

##### >>> `display(df.head(5))`

[image]

##### >>> `HTML(grouped_df.sample(5).to_html(escape=False))`

[image]

For example, if the user click on "Download the details (`.csv`)" of the second row, he should get a `.csv` of all rows in `df` where the column car equals to "Ford Torino 500".

By the way, the code will be implemented in a [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) app.

Is there any way to achieve this ? Do you have any propositions, please ?

#### EDIT :

By following [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas)'s brilliant suggestion, I came up with this code :

```
csv = df.to_csv(index=False, sep=';')
b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
payload = b64.decode()

grouped_df['DownloadCsv'] = grouped_df['DownloadCsv'].apply(
    lambda x: f'<a download="{x}.csv" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{x}</a>')

st.write(HTML(grouped_df.sample(5).to_html(escape=False)), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Comment: The first thing came to my mind is the following: you need to fetch index value of the pressed button, i.e. once you click on the row with the `Ford Torino 500` -- you should fetch its index, then create another dataframe, filtered by that index value. Then, you need to export it via `to_csv('filename.csv')` method. Finally, the `<a href = 'link'>` tag should be linked to that exact path where that `filename.csv` is located.

Comment: Hi @Niqua, the problem is filename.csv is located nowhere (in memory I guess). For example, when I download a .csv on my streamlit (hosted locally), the .csv has this http://localhost:8501/media/2a7651a0659c83163aea6d6321af3f86945b9ad133abd92c7eebeed2.csv?title=CarsApp as a URL.

Comment: if you have data in memory then you may try to use `io.StringIO` to create file-like object in memory and write in this file as csv. And later you can convert text to `base64` and use special construction `<a href="data:text/csv;base64," + data_in_base64">`

Comment: Hi @furas, thank you so much. I'm not familiar with `io.StringIO`. Can you make a proposition of code, please ?

Comment: It can be complex but you can see it in some examples with `Flask` to send file or image generated in code or uploaded by `<form>`. But using `st.download_button` seems much simpler. [Flask: How to use BytesIO in Flask to display matplotlib image without saving in file. — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-flask-how-to-use-bytesio-in-flask-to-display-matplotlib-image-without-saving-in-file-gb.html)

Comment: Thank you so much @furas, I managed to build the code I was looking for. Check out the EDIT I made to my post. There is only one issue left, I still can't filter the dataframe. The downloaded .csv carry all the rows and not only the row I selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73396490/19603419), I explain how I managed to filter the dataframe/csv downloaded.

**Note** = I don't know why yet but the type of all the columns has to be `string`

So I needed to add this :

```
df_columns = list(grouped_df)  # Creates list of all column headers
grouped_df[all_columns] = grouped_df[all_columns].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you aim to integrate this in `streamlit`, why not use a [streamlit button](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/how-download-pandas-dataframe-csv) to download the csv?
The example below writes the dataframe to streamlit [columns](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns) and adds download buttons for the individual csv files.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cars.csv", delimiter=';', skiprows=[1])

grouped_df = df.groupby('Car').agg(NumberOfCars=('Car', 'size'), 
                                   MeanOfWeight=('Weight', 'mean'),
                                   MeanOfAcceleration=('Acceleration', 'mean')).reset_index()

grouped_df.insert(len(grouped_df.columns), "DownloadCsv", 'Download the details (.csv)')

colms = st.columns((2, 1, 1, 1, 2))

#write headers
for col, field_name in zip(colms, grouped_df.columns):
    col.write(f'**{field_name}**')

def writerow(row):
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = st.columns((2, 1, 1, 1, 2))
    with col1:
        st.write(row['Car'])
    with col2:
        st.write(row['NumberOfCars'])
    with col3:
        st.write(row['MeanOfWeight'])
    with col4:
        st.write(row['MeanOfAcceleration'])
    with col5:
        st.download_button("Download details (.csv)", df[df['Car'] == row['Car']].to_csv(), f"details_{row['Car']}.csv", "text/csv")
        
grouped_df.apply(writerow, axis=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @RJ Adriaansen, thank you for the beautiful workaround. There is only one issue, imagine the grouped_df has thousands of rows, in this case streamlit will probalby crash. Is there a way we can split the result into multiples tabs (1, 2, ...) ?

Comment: I would still suggest this solution if the dataframe is particularly large, since the other option - to write all the data into the html code by creating `base64` urls would make the html huge. If you want to stick to a table-like display you could try using [bokeh](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/make-streamlit-table-results-hyperlinks-or-add-radio-buttons-to-table/7883/2) though

Comment: @L'Artiste I would give the st.button version a try. If it isn't performant enough, you could paginate the table using st.session_state like this https://towardsdatascience.com/pagination-in-streamlit-82b62de9f62b

Comment: @ZacharyBlackwood, thank you so much. I'll try to use RJ Adriaansen's solution + yours (pagination) and see how much performant the app will be.