# How to create a conditionnal column that carry the URL of a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, io, base64

I'm trying to make a conditionnal column using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

The goal is : when I click on the button `Click here`, I should get a csv with only the row matching the community chosen (in our case, a dataframe with one single row and one single column=Community).

##### CODE :

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
import base64

df = pd.DataFrame({'Community': ['StackOverflow','GISExchange', 'DBAExchange']})

df.insert(1, "URL", 'Click here')

csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
payload = b64.decode()

df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(
    lambda x: f'<a download="{x}.csv" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{x}</a>')
```

##### >>> `HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))`

[image]

The problem with the code above is that the hyperlink `Click here`, gives a csv with the hole dataframe (including the three rows).

Do you know how to fix that ? Do you have any suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, I end up with the code below that answer my question.

I first created a function that decode the csv and so I can filter the dataframe.
Then, replaced the .apply method with a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
import base64

df = pd.DataFrame({'Community': ['StackOverflow','GISExchange', 'DBAExchange']})

df.insert(1, "URL", 'Click here')

def pyld(val):
    csv = df[df['Community']==val]['Community'].to_csv(index=False)
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
    payload = b64.decode()
    return payload

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    row['URL'] = f'<a download="data.csv" href="data:text/csv;base64,{pyld(df["Community"][i])}" target="_blank">Click here</a>'
```

##### >>> `HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
df['URL'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"<a href=\"https://{x['Community_name']}.com/\">{x['Community_name']}</a>", axis=1)
```

OR, without the use of apply

```
df['URL'] = "<a href=\"https://" + df['Community_name'] + ".com/\">" + df['Community_name'] + "</a>"
df
```

```
    Community       URL
0   StackOverflow   <a href="https://StackOverflow.com/">StackOver...
1   GISExchange     <a href="https://GISExchange.com/">GISExchange...
2   DBAExchange     <a href="https://DBAExchange.com/">DBAExchange...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Naveed. I have a small question though. What if the column name is not `"Community"` but something like `"Community-Full_name"`, how can we use in this case the .apply approach ?

Comment: updated the solution, you escape the quotes/apostrophe

Comment: I applied it to my original dataset and I got an `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. I will update my question to be more precise.

Comment: Naveed, please consider the clarifications I added to my question. Thank you so much !

Comment: @L'Artiste, you are encoding the whole of DF and then using that single encoded string in to create URL, this won't work. to encode a URL you may want to post a separate question on how to encode a column in a dataframe,

Comment: Thank you @Naveed for the answer. Unfortunately, I won't be able to create a third question for the same topic/issue/question. Do you any suggestions please ? Is there a way we can create a function that will filter the dataframe df ?

Comment: Naveed, do you have the solution for our problem ? If so, I can accept this question and create a new one.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not sure on how to encode the URL in a DF :(